# SQL SERVER COMO ENCUENTRO EL NUMERO DE UNA COLUMNA MAS LAS VECES QUE SE DUPLICA OTRA COLUMNA EN ELLAS

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Como realizo esta consulta, adjunto imagen]

Como realizo esta consulta, adjunto imagen

Comment: Te recomiendo leer Cómo preguntar. Deberías de poner la estructura de la tabla, los datos de ejemplo y las querys en texto. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una posible solución es utilizar una tabla de expresión común y utilizar dos conjuntos para obtener los datos.

```
Create table dbo.info (estudio varchar(20), Dato int);
GO
Insert into dbo.info(estudio, Dato)
values
('Estudio 1',123),
('Estudio 1',123),
('Estudio 1',123),
('Estudio 1',234),
('Estudio 1',561),
('Estudio 2',123),
('Estudio 2',123),
('Estudio 2',561),
('Estudio 3',123),
('Estudio 3',561),
('Estudio 3',234),
('Estudio 3',234),
('Estudio 3',234),
('Estudio 3',123);
go
;with cte as (
Select estudio as Estudio, dato, count(*) as veces
From dbo.info 
group by estudio, dato
), agrupados as (
Select estudio, count(*) as num
from dbo.info
group by estudio
) Select a.estudio
        , a.num as Cantidad
        , sum(case when c.veces = 1 then 0 else c.veces - 1 end) as Datos_repetidos
     from agrupados a 
    inner join cte c 
    on a.estudio = c.Estudio
    group by a.estudio, a.num
Order by estudio
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Tablas de expresión común](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-1/)

[Tablas de expresión común. Correlativas](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-2-correlativos/)

Comment: amigo es usted muy amable por su respuesta es correcta, muchas gracias!